# Installing 8.1 Windows | Removing Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

I'am running Ubuntu right now ( 32 bit) , I burned the **Windows 8.1 ISO (64 bit)** on my 
USB
now when I launch my USB on boot , I have language select , then accept terms ...
and when I have to choose Parititions of where to install Windows 8.1 , I get the following error : "Nous n'avons pas pu créer de partition, ni localiser une partition"
It's in french , sry . (In English: We did not create a partition or locate a partition)

I tried to delete the Parition and make new ones same error (Do I have to delete the System Partition ? and remake ?) since I can't install over it because it's not NTFS

**& NO , I'am not planning to dual boot , I just wanna remove Ubuntu & put WIndows**

gparted :

[image]

Comment: post the screenshot of your gparted partition editor.

Comment: Done , edited. please take a look :)

Comment: Why do you duplicate your own questions?

Comment: It is easy. The answer is provided at the following link : http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 0):

Grab a Ubuntu LiveUSB (the bootable USB or CD/DVD you used for installing Ubuntu), use it to wipe your disk (using `gparted`), boot from your Windows 8.1 ISO and create partitions and then install Windows 8.1

#### Wiping Hardish with `gparted`:

- Open `gparted`
- Select your disk and click the "Create new Partition Table" option from the "Device" menu, select `msdos` as partition type and click apply.
  [image]

**This will wipe your HDD, backup anything you want**

Now you may continue with installation of Windows 8.1

Comment: I really didn't understand , what is a LiveUSB and how I'll do all that :(

Comment: @user3091970 never mind, editing the answer

Comment: @user3091970 check the updated answer

Comment: "Grab a Ubuntu LiveUSB (the bootable USB or CD/DVD you used for installing Ubuntu), use it to wipe your disk (using gparted), boot from your Windows 8.1 ISO and create partitions and then install Windows 8.1"

I didn't get that part :x how I'll use the USB that I used to install Ubuntu o_o

Comment: @user3091970 You may have used a USb to install Ubuntu. Boot from the USB, you used to install ubuntu, run gparted from it and follow the instructions to wipe your HDD

Comment: when I try to make new table . IT tells me there is 2 Partitions in use :x

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14133/discussion-between-cshubhamrao-and-user3091970)

Comment: oh , so I Don't run Gparted from the Ubuntu that I'am using here ? but from the bootable USB ?